# setting minversion from the command line

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge, appx, desktop-app-converter

When running the desktop app converter it's generating a bunch of lines saying things like

> Shell verb "open" was detected for file type association '.mpeg'. Windows app packages can only use this verb on Windows 10 Creators Update (10.0.15063.0) or later. The corresponding AppxManifest.xml entry is commented out to keep this Windows app package compatible with earlier versions of Windows 10. To enable this feature, uncomment it and change the "MinVersion" attribute on the "TargetDeviceFamily" element to 10.0.15063.0.

Ok, fine, but automating your build process is a lot easier if you can just run the converter without having to edit the manifest and repackage the appx afterward.  Is there some way to set the MinVersion attribute from the command line of the converter?

Comment: You shouldn't have to run the DAC as part of your build process. Run it once to get the package layout and get the manifest right. Then as part of your build process you just drop the new binaries into the package layout and call makeappx. Any reason this wouldn't work for your scenario?

Comment: Because Makeappx chokes on the resources.pri file that the converter creates.